# Automatically linking to functions (or modules) from the README file in Hackage

Tags: haskell, haddock, hackage

Is there any way for the README file to support automatic linking to known identifiers (eg. function names or module names), similar to how [Haddock does it](https://haskell-haddock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#hyperlinked-identifiers) ?

Comment: To clarify: are you talking about the README as given at the bottom of the Hackage page, [like this one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod#readme)? If so, I don’t think there’s any way to link automatically (but I could be wrong), although there’s nothing stopping you from simply manually adding hyperlinks to the appropriate identifiers.

Comment: @bradrn yes - that readme. If I manually add links, won't the need to be updated every time I bump the version of the library, else they'll keep pointing to the previous version, right?

Comment: Yes, I believe they will. (Although admittedly I’ve never published anything on Hackage yet, so I’m probably not the best person to talk about this.)

Comment: If you elide the version number in the Hackage URL, it will always be redirected to the latest package version. E.g. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:head will always point at `Data.List.head` in the latest `base` on Hackage.